# Css bootstrap forms (rails newbie)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add some styling into my user_form using css bootstrap.

This is how it looks at the minute:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I was trying to put it in the form of:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name"  placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputConfirmPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputConfirmPassword1" placeholder="Password">

  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My problem is that I dont know how to add the functionality to the css form. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance!

------ EDIT 1 -------

In order to clarify what is happening:

my _user_form.html.erb at the minute looks like the first set of code. However when I delete it and replace it with the second set of code nothing works.

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161210221810) do
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
  end

end
```

Comment: what do you mean by add the functionality to the css form??

Comment: @Mohammad.Gh so when I press submit none of the params are passed

Comment: can explain clearly, what do you trying to achieve, what is the issue?

Comment: @IgorIvancha I think you would understand better if you read the comments on the answer below. So what happens is that when I run the second code nothing gets submitted. How can i send the params :name , :email, :password using  the css layout.

Comment: @Eltorero1992, show, please, `schema.rb`

Comment: @IgorIvancha please see edit 1

Comment: ok! do you have `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` in `Gemfile` (`bundle install`) and `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";` in any `.scss` ?

Comment: So I do have it installed and @import "bootstrap"; in my custom.scss.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the label:

`<%= f.label :name, class: "my_class" %>`

Answer (score 0):

at the first you need to use  that include your form items, and then in javascript send params to your backend! for example

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: so it would look something like:
`<form action ="user_form.html.erb method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" name = value  placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>`
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: and in this case must handle the form data and sending them in here: "user_form.html.erb"